# web chat bot not responding

Tags: .net, azure, botframework

My .net BOT hosted in web chat is neither responding nor showing any error at application insight.This error had been earlier some months ago but at that time it gave "Gateway timeout" error and next day it started working automatically.But this time it showed same "Gateway timeout" error but doesn't get started even after 1 day and now it is neither responding nor showing error.Meantime my azure subscription plan changed from S1 to F1 but now I changed it to S1 again.

Comment: My BOT SDK version is 3.12.2

Comment: 1)you can try to contact your bot with the Bot Framework Emulator and check if it can respond as expected. 2)you can try to restart the app service that is hosting your bot application and check if it can mitigate the issue.3)if possible, you can redeploy your bot application to Azure and check if it work well.

Comment: Tried all the suggestions and result are as follows: 1.) Working fine with emulator. 2.) Restarted the app service but issue still persists. 3.) Publish the same app again but no worked for me. Now I will try to create a new instance of it and will let you know what happens

Comment: `Working fine with emulator.` Do you mean that it work as expected if you connect emulator to the bot hosting on Azure and test it? Does the issue only appear when you test it in web chat on Azure portal?

Comment: Also, try upgrading to the latest Bot Builder sdk: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder v3.15.2.2

Comment: Thanks all, my bot limit to send 10000 messages had been reached thats why it was showing such a behaviour.